# log4net logging from web app

Tags: logging, log4net

I have a framework library which would do a lot of things including logging. We are using log4net for logging. This framework has the static logging class LogManager, a static instance of ILog (logger) and static methods for logging INFO, WARNING, DEBUG etc.

The static instance logger is getting initialized like  this:

```cs
public static class LogManager
{        
    private static ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    static ActivityLogManager()
    {

    }

    public static void LogDebugy(string message, params object[] messageParameters)
    {
        // Log the message here
    }
}
```

I have my own doubts if this is the right way to do it. I see from [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2005/03/07/ConfiguringLog4NetForWebApplications.aspx) that each class which needs to log, should declare a static instance of `ILog`.

Also I see that I would have to specify the Log4net config file in my framework project to log.  Thought I read [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/01/13/SettingUpLog4NetForMultiLayeredApplications.aspx) that the config would get picked up from the executing assembly, but I don't see it happen.

Is there any way that I can have my logging done from my framework class with the configuration getting picked up from my web application (for my web app) or some other business library project (for my business class libraries)?

I would also like to add some custom info into my log (like custom business object ID etc, application pool, ServerName, ClientHostName, ClientBrowser, ClientOS, Client User etc). Is it possible?

I am using AdoNetAppender.

Edit1: Am using `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = @"log4net.config", Watch = true)` in my assembly.cs to point to log4net config file.

Edit2: My `ILog Logger` is in my framework LogManager Class, so only one instance is generated for my  application.

Comment: Usually each class that needs to log something have their own ILog instances, preferably with a name which indicates some sort of hiearchy (Namespace + Type is common.) This allows one to filter the messages. NHibernate does this which allows you, for example, to filter out messages from some sublibraries and dump all SQL-queries (which are usually logged in DEBUG).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of questions but about the first question, I use this style for the logger:

```
private static ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

Of course you can name the variable whatever you like, but this is recommended by the log4net team I think, as this results in only one `ILog`-instance per instance of your class.

This is more or less what you are doing already so nothing to worry about there. I'm not sure why you are going the long way through the executing method though.

I usually place the config in the Web.config or App.config. I couldn't deduce if you use any of these for config. If you do use them it's simple. You just add a [configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) section for log4net and add the loggers, appenders and filters you need.

If you want to log custom data you can either add it into the log-message, e.g:

```
Log.WarnFormat(
    "Reactor malfunction, temperature {0} celsius."
    + "Evacuate sector {1} immediately", 
    temp, 
    sector);
```

Or if the values needed are stored in some object, you can make a "renderer" for that type, which will custom print when the object is handed as a logging message, e.g `Log.Warn(myObjWithCustomFormatting)`.

A object renderer must derive from `IObjectRenderer` and register it in the configuration.

Comment: I use the above but with System.Reflection.Methodbase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType() to get the type of the class automatically. Since this occurs only when the constructor is called its fairly cheap.

Comment: I see what you mean. A matter of preference I guess.

Comment: Thanks Skurmedal: I am not using web.config or app.config, am using assembly.cs (see my Edit). Also I am not talking about format, when I mean I want to log custom objects. I see that using InfoFormat or WarnFormat logs it into my DB column -message. I would want to create a custom column in DB and store some custom info

Comment: Oh okay, I think you might need to create your own Appender then.

Answer (score 1):

We use log4net in a number of our webapps and they are fine. There is some special setup that needs to be done if you want to log to the event log from a webapp, and it depends on which version of windows you are using. In short it requires you to grant permission to the running user to write to the event log. Under Win 7, 2008 etc you must grant the whole branch permission, all others its just the specific app-log.

If you want to log to a file, just make sure the file is in the apps directory and it should be fine.

If you do not declare the configuration for the logging in your log framework, but delay it until your app calls it, this will happen by default with the log4net configuration section. If it is loaded earlier then no, the first loaded version will be used, unless you override it in code.